How long does it take a Jellyfloat to digest Pikmin?
The Pikmin wiki says that Jellyfloats are enemies in Pikmin 2 that will suck up Pikmin and slowly digest them. You can rescue Pikmin by killing a Jellyfloat before the Pikmin is digested.
How long do I have to rescue a sucked up Pikmin from a Jellyfloat before the Pikmin is fully digested?

Can't find an exact number, wikis only say "considerably long periods of time".
